# Creating a grid/mesh with nodes from outside to center

Tags: python, grid, mesh

New to python so apologies if this is not clear, but i'm trying to construct a mesh with x axis ranging from -4000 to 4000 and y axis from -4000 to 4000.

Im trying to split each axis into 100 nodes, but i want node 1 to be at (-4000,-4000) ie bottom left corner and essentially for the nodes to pass around the outside of the grid travelling in, so my final node would be at the very center of the grid.

Im tryin to do this as i'm running a for loop and I need to loop through the nodes in the correct order when reading their x and y value. I havent made grids on python before, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are more concerned about readability and not performance, I would recommend to first create your square grid, then sort it in a "spiral" configuration.

Considering your Node class:

```
class Node:
    "Node of the grid"
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

You want to create 100 nodes per axis (first one is at -4000, one is at 0, last is at 3200):

```
nodes = []
for x in range(-4000, 4001, 800): # From -4000 to 4000 (included) by 800 increment  
    for y in range(-4000, 4000, 800):
        nodes.append(Node(x,y))
```

Then to have it sorted as you want, you want something similar to polar coordinates and sort by radius then angle (I said similar because your nodes are arranged into a square not a circle). Radius here would be `max(abs(x),abs(y)` instead of the normal radius.

The sorting code would looks like this:

```
import math
sorted_nodes = []
for node in nodes:
    # We take atan2 to compute the phase but the starting point would not be on bootom left corner
    # So we need to add a constant (0.001 is a small number to make the bottom left corner to have maximum value)
    # We use this trick to still be able in reverse order
    phase = (math.atan2(node.y, node.x) + 3 * math.pi / 4 - 0.001) % (2 * math.pi)
    sorted_nodes.append((max(abs(node.x),abs(node.y)), phase, node))
sorted_nodes = sorted(sorted_nodes, reverse=True) # Sort first by radius, then by the phase
```

The `sorted_nodes` list is a tuple with the third argument being your nodes well sorted, (you could just get a list of your nodes with [`t[2] for t in sorted_nodes]`).

*Note: The list is going clockwise*